# Sandbox Paypal Api access currently offline?

Tags: paypal, sandbox

sandbox.paypal.com -> Profile & Settings -> Selling Tools -> API access

Can anyone else have problems entering this page? I get blank page (500 error)

Answer (score 0):

Nope, its up and running.

here is a screenshot taken just now [image]

Comment: Please click on "Update" under "API access" -> i get blank screen.

Comment: its working man, and just for this troubles you should accept this answer, here is the screenshot after clicking there : http://imgur.com/a/xyx6c

Comment: Thanks, I'm creating new sanbox then.

Comment: Nope not working [link]https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/businessmanage/credentials/apiAccess

Comment: Navigating directly to https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/businessprofile/mytools/apiaccess/firstparty/signature i was able to get API keys